# Adding external Ids to Partners in OpenERP withouth a new module

Tags: python, xml-rpc, odoo

My Question is a bit complex and iam new to `OpenERP`.

I have an external database and an OpenERP. the external one isn't PostgreSQL. 
MY job is that I need to synchronize the partners in the two databases. 
External one being the more important. This means that if the external one's data change so does the OpenERp's, but if OpenERP's data changes nothing changes onthe external one.

- I can access to the external database, and using XML RCP I have acces
  to OpenERP's as well.
- I can import data from the external database simply with XML RCP but 
  the problem is the sync.
- I can't just INSERT the modified partner and delete the old one
  because i have no way to identify the old one.
- I need to UPDATE it. But then i need an id that says which is which. 
  and external ID.
- To my knowledge OpenERP can handle external IDs.

How does this work? and how can i add an external ID to my res.partner using this?

I was told that I cant create a new module for this alone I need to use the internal ID works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**: have a look at the way the CSV Import and Export wizard work - exporting a record automatically creates an *external identifier* so you can re-import that same CSV and the record will be updated rather than re-created.

**Long answer**:
OpenERP stores external IDs in the `ir.model.data` table, which you can access in the user interface via the Settings menu <sup>[1](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.export_data)</sup>. This simple table maps an "External Identifier" in the form `module_name.record_identifier` to a pair `(model,res_id)` that points to the actual table and row.

These external IDs are used to find the database-local row that corresponds to a record created by some external source: a module (hence the `module`-based namespace) or an imported CSV file, usually.

For example the external identifier `base.EUR` maps to the database records that holds the EUR currency in the database, and is owned by the `base` module.

As of version 6.1, OpenERP automatically creates new external identifiers for all OpenERP records that are **exported** using the sidebar *Export* wizard: they're exported in a CSV column named `id`.

And if such an `id` column is present in a CSV file that is **imported** via the *Import* wizard, OpenERP will also create an external identifier to remember it. And when the external identifier already exists, the record is updated rather than created.

In theory, all you have to do is produce a proper CSV file with an extra `id` column<sup>[2](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.import_data)</sup> from your master database (you could even use the actual DB ID), and import it in OpenERP. You should then be able to re-import updated versions of this CSV file whenever you want.

**References:**

- The *Import* and *Export* wizards basically call the API methods [export_data](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.export_data) and [import_data](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.import_data), so you can script this via XML-RPC if needed.
- The [`ir.model.data`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/trunk/view/4763/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py#L772) model stores the external identifiers (historically called XML IDs because it corresponds to the `id` field of XML records in module data files).

---

<sup>[1](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.export_data)</sup> In OpenERP 6.1 it is located under *Settings>Configuration>Sequences & Identifiers>External Identifiers*, and in OpenERP version 7 under *Settings>Technical>Sequences & Identifiers>External Identifiers*.

<sup>[2](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.import_data)</sup> can be any string with no dot "`.`" character in it: it will be stored in a special `__export__` module namespace)

Comment: the 'id' column's content per row can be even an external row id? or that id is set by OpenERP?

Answer (score 3):

> the 'id' column's content per row can be even an external row id? or that id is set by OpenERP?

The id is setup by OpenERP if it is not present, otherwise it uses whatever external row id you put in there.

> I don't see an ir.model.data in 7.0

ir.model.data is there at version 7.0 - how were you searching for it?

> nor a sidebar Export Wizard.

At version 7, you now need to enable exporting/importing.

http://forum.openerp.com/forum/topic35830.html

Comment: that is awesome! than if i just use the import module with CSV and automate it i can syncro two different database! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add an integer field in res partner table for storing external id on both database. When data is retrived from the external server and adding to your openerp database, store the external id in the record of res partner in local server and also save the id of the newly created partner record in the external server's partner record. So next time when the external partner record is updated, we can search the external id in our local server and update that record. 
Please check the openerp module base_synchronization and read the codes, which will be helpful for you.

Comment: but adding a field means making an addon, doesn't it? Also i cant find any base_synchronization in 7.0...

Comment: Nevermind. New orders from up above: i need to crate a OpenERP module that deals with syncro. thank yoou for the help nonetheless.

Comment: @Anoma: keeping track of external identifiers for database records is a built-in feature of the OpenERP framework, no need for extra columns or a module for this. It works out-of-the box for module data or imported/exported CSV files for instance.